# Как сохранить видео без сжатия?

Tags: windows, видео, кодек

Нужно на скорую руку смонтировать видео. Но сохранить видео **без** сжатия. Выбрал `Movie maker`. Подскажите, можно ли сохранить там видео без потери качества?

Comment: В самой программе нет сохранения без потери качества, но есть "Наилучшее качество". Насколько оно наилучшее судите сами, смотря под какие задачи.

Comment: @Invision Древняя, но стоит на компе и ей можно быстро состряпать на коленке что-нибудь. Это и требовалось. Если можно без потери -- хорошо. Нет -- плохо, но не страшно.

Comment: @Invision спасибо

Comment: Я в свое время использовал Sony Vegas, не знаю как у них сейчас дела обстоят, но с любыми задачами справлялась на ура

Comment: @Invision разумеется. Я юзал Ulead Visual Studio, когда ещё школоло был. Хорошая, простая в понимании програмулина. Но осиливает 95% задач. Sony Vegas явно сложнее. Но с Ulead Visual Studio вышел косяк с кряками, поэтому я на это дело быстро забил. И нашёл простое решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Есть кроссплатформенная простая программа [Avidemux](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avidemux). Среди прочего - умеет сохранять аудио и видеопотоки без модификации.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Этого сделать нельзя. Movie maker предполагает только сжатие с минимальными потерями. Но это будет именно сжатие, а не сохранение без потерь качества.